# How to check what version of Ember.js is loaded?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How can I check in a browser console what version of Ember.js is loaded? I know I can check it in the library code, on its top

```
/*!
 * @overview  Ember - JavaScript Application Framework
 * @copyright Copyright 2011-2016 Tilde Inc. and contributors
 *            Portions Copyright 2006-2011 Strobe Inc.
 *            Portions Copyright 2008-2011 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license   Licensed under MIT license
 *            See https://raw.github.com/emberjs/ember.js/master/LICENSE
 * @version   2.4.1
 */
```

like [here](http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v2.4.1/ember.debug.js), but let's say I have two versions and want to check on the fly which one has been loaded. How can I do this in a console?

Comment: I think you could make an ajax GET request on the url of your JS file and parse it to find the version number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [source code](http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v2.4.1/ember.debug.js) of the library there's defined version property:

```
 /**
    The semantic version.

    @property VERSION
    @type String
    @default '2.4.1'
    @static
    @public
  */
  Ember.VERSION = '2.4.1';
```

To check version of Ember.js in a console simply put

`Ember.VERSION`

You can see it works on http://emberjs.com/ home page:

```
> Ember.VERSION
> "2.2.0"
```

Answer (score 20):

In the Browser console You can type

**Ember.VERSION**

to get the version number of the loaded Ember.js library.

Answer (score 2):

install the [ember-inspector](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/ember-inspector/installation/) addon and you'll find all the info you need in the 'info' tab.

Answer (score 0):

The question also mentions library code, so I thought I would include this here in case somebody gets here and is working with addons.

https://github.com/pzuraq/ember-compatibility-helpers

Example usage [here](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-router-scroll/blob/e8fc2bab4823790c034a6b5639709834a4944111/addon/index.js)